# ckeditor multiple custom toolbars

Tags: ckeditor

Hello I'm trying to create multiple toolbars in my config.js file
What I have now is this:

```
config.height = '300px';
config.uiColor = '#edf5ff';
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3'
config.toolbar = 'standard';
config.toolbar_standard = [ 
    ['Source', 'Maximize'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','SpellChecker','-','Scayt'],
    ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace'],
    ['Image','Table','HorizontalRule'],
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'],      
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','RemoveFormat'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
    ['TextColor','BGColor'],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
    ['Format','FontSize'],
];
config.toolbar = 'lite';
config.toolbar_lite = [ 
    ['Source', 'Maximize'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','SpellChecker','-','Scayt'],
];
```

I want to set the toolbar **standard** as my default toolbar.

and in some forms I want to call the **lite** toolbar.

how do I do this?

Regards Ralph

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

```
$params = array();
            $params ['toolbar'] = "lite";
            $editor = new Ckeditor($params);
```